# JavaScript Sort based on external object

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of objects based on the appearance of a key in an external object. For some reason, I'm not able to sort the array and I tried using lodash or other methods..

Here's a more simple example:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
obj = { 4: true, 6: true }

arr.sort((a, b) => obj[a] - obj[b])
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I would like the truth-y values to be first, as in `[4, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5]`

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't subtract `true` and `undefined` (which is the value for keys that don't exist).

```
> arr.sort((a, b) => (obj[b] || 0) - (obj[a] || 0))
(6) [4, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

works instead (i.e. coercing that `undefined` to zero).